# ffmpeg: How to Use Flip, Concat and Speed up Multiple Videos Together?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Code1: Merge Videos

```
ffmpeg -i   input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -vsync 2 -map "[v]" -map "[a]"    output1.mp4
```

Code2: Flip and Speed Up Video

```
ffmpeg -i   outpu1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]hflip,setpts=0.77*PTS;[0:a]atempo=1.3" output2.mp4
```

How can we combine that codes together? Please Help Me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a];[v]hflip,setpts=PTS/1.3;[a]atempo=1.3" output.mp4
```